# How to delete a line between two lines which match a certain pattern in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

**input** of my file is:

```
bsg23
< Hi James
ab89n
> Hi Jamy
nd87a
< What about weekend?
90hsg
> What about sat/sun?
```

and **output** should come :

```
< Hi James
> Hi Jamy
< What about weekend?
> What about sat/sun?
```

Means deleting the contents of the line before '>' and '<'.

Can anyone help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In Notepad++ 6.9.1 I was able to do this by selecting Search->Replace... and putting the following regular expression in the "Find what:" field:

```
(^[^<>\n]+)\n|\n[^<>\n]+
```

Then leaving the "Replace with:" field empty and setting a Search Mode of "Regular Expression", leaving ". matches newline" unchecked, and pressing "Replace All".

### How It Works

`(^[^<>\n]+)\n|\n[^<>\n]+` is a [Notepad++ Regular Expression](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions).

`(^[^<>\n]+)\n` Is a sub-expression that matches lines that don't start with `<` or `>`. This matches the first line of text in your example input "bsg23".

`|` Indicates alternation between two sub-expressions

`\n[^<>\n]+` Matches a newline followed by characters that are not `<`, `>`, or a newline. This matches the newlines at the end of lines that start with `<` or `>` and the following text on the next line.